# Adding elements to list with arbitrary dimension

Tags: tensors

Suppose we have list like below:

```
{{{1,2},{3,4}},{{5,6},{7,8}}}
```

How to add list below to old list

```
{{{9},{10}},{{11},{12}}}
```

to compose list below:

```
{{{1,2,9},{3,4,10}},{{5,6,11},{7,8,12}}}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
lst1 = {{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}, {{5, 6}, {7, 8}}};
lst2 = {{{9}, {10}}, {{11}, {12}}};
MapThread[Join, {lst1, lst2}, 2]
(* {{{1, 2, 9}, {3, 4, 10}}, {{5, 6, 11}, {7, 8, 12}}} *)
```

Comment: Or simply `Join[lst1, lst2, 3]`